# How to eager load only 1 result from many to many relationship Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

How can I eager load only one from many to many relationship?

I have two models `Application` & `Applicant`

`Models\Application.php`

```
public function applicants() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Applicant::class);
}

public function oneApplicant() {
    return $this->applicants()->first();
}
```

I'm wanted to paginate on the applications and want to load only one applicant (if they have.)

```
return Application::stage( $stages )
->stagenot($stageNot)
->refered( $refered, $term )
->with(['oneApplicant'])
->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate( $count );
```

But it isn't working.
Getting the first result like this `return $this->applicants()->first()`
will produce an error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()`

If I also put a limit instead of first `return $this->applicants()->limit(1)` it will only show one applicant to the last collection.

I also tried to modify the query directly on eager loading call to get the first row

```
return Application::with(['applicants',  => function( $query ) {
        $q->first();
    }])->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate( $count );
```

But the result is the same as adding a `limit(1)` on directly on the relation, it will only add one applicant to the last item from collection and the other item have empty array value

Can anybody help :)

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this package https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Comment: thats interesting, I thought it wasn't so complex to do it and laravel have built-in function to do it, thanks anyway :)

Comment: You can use this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64440891/how-to-return-one-instance-of-a-eloquent-many-to-many-relation-with-eager-loadin/64477850#64477850

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized its too complex to achieve it myself and ended up using the [eloquent-eager-limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit) package from [staudenmeir](https://github.com/staudenmeir) (big thanks to him, save me hours of work :) )

here's my model

```php
class Application extends BaseModel {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;

    public function applicants() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Applicant::class);
    }

    public function oneApplicant() {
        return $this->applicants()->limit(1);
    }
}
```

Then I was able to use it on my controller

```php
return Application::stage( $stages )
    ->stagenot($stageNot)
    ->refered( $refered, $term )
    ->with([
        'oneApplicant',
        'oneApplicant.onePhone:model_id,number',
        'oneApplicant.oneAddress:model_id,state'
    ])->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate( $count );
```