# How to return one instance of a eloquent many to many relation with eager loading?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
class Parent extends Model
{
    public function kids()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Kid')
            ->orderBy('age')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function oldestKid()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Kid')
            ->orderByDesc('age')
            ->take(1);
    }
}
```

Problem with this approach is that `$parent->oldestKid` returns an array. It would feel more logical if it would return an object.

`$parent = App\Models\Parent::with('oldestKid')->first();`

Comment: IIRC `belongsToMany()` returns a collection regardless of how many results there are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is what we ended up with, and its working.**

Important to add: the pivot table is kid_parent

```
public function oldestKid()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Kid::class, 'oldest_kid_id', 'id');
}

public function scopeWithOldestKid($query)
{
    $query->addSelect(['oldest_kid_id' => KidParent::select('kid_id')
        ->whereColumn('parent_id', 'parents.id')
        ->join('kids', 'kids.id', '=', 'kid_parent.kid_id')
        ->orderByDesc('kids.age')
        ->take(1)
    ])->with('oldestKid');
}
```

then you can use it like that :

```
$parents = Parent::withOldestKid()->get();

foreach($parents as $parent){
 $oldest_kid = $parent->oldestKid;
 
}
```

If you want to go crazy: you can use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes so it is always loaded in if you go for a parent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a subquery to do that :

```php
    public function oldestKid()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Kid::class);
    }

    public function scopeWithOldestKid($query)
    {
        $query->addSelect(['oldest_kid_id' => Kid::select('id')
            ->whereColumn('parent_id', 'parents.id')
            -> orderByDesc('age')
            ->take(1)
        ])->with('oldestKid');
    }
```

then you can use it like that :

```
$parents = Parent::withOldestKid()->get();

foreach($parents as $parent){
 $oldest_kid = $parent->oldestKid;
 
}
```

Comment: this would maybe work with a one-to-many relation. But this is about an many-to-many relationship. (One kid can have multiple parents, one parent can have multiple kids).


But thanks for giving us a good direction.

We adapted your answer..